# Convert the argument (a variable) into string a string automatically

Tags: javascript

I made a temperature conversion function and I am curious if there is anyway to automatically convert an argument into a string.

For instance, convertTemp(72, F) --> convertTemp(72, 'F') and then start the function.

I know I can just enter the argument in as a string, but It got me wondering if there was a way to turn a (somehow erroneously entered) variable declaration into a string without having to deal with the Reference error saying that the argument is not defined (declared).

I've been looking through the `toString()` method, `String()`, etc. but they all convert values not an implicit variable like format would be.

If it's not possible that's fine, just a curiosity.

Thanks!

```
function convertTemp(temperature, format) {
    if (format == 'C') return CtoF();
    else if (format == 'F') return FtoC();
    else return 'Invalid Metric';

    function CtoF() {
        let F = Math.floor((1.8) * temperature + 32);
        return F;
    }

    function FtoC() {
        let C = Math.floor(((temperature - 32) * 5) / 9);
        return C;
    }
}
```

TLDR; function is entered as: convertTemp(72, F) instead of convertTemp(72, 'F'), can this be automatically corrected?

Comment: `const F = 'F';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is technically "no".

You'd have to do some pretty hacky stuff to avoid a `ReferenceError` and none of it would be efficient and would be bound to cause bugs, but just for fun I've come up with just the kind of hack that should make most programmers cringe.

***Disclaimer: Under no circumstances would I recommend ever doing this***

First let's consider a function that simply outputs its arguments

```
function doStuff(...args){
  console.log("Args:", ...args)
}
```

If you try and pass this function a variable, that variable has to be defined somewhere. As other users have stated, a global variable would be the only way to ensure the variable is defined in any scope, and we will be using that later.

If you surround a reference error with try/catch, then it's possible to catch the reference error's message. Then using regex you can extract the missing parameter, which luckily will already be a string, add it to the global scope, then simply call the function again.

```
try {
  doStuff(A)
} catch (e) {
  const [,arg] = e.message.match(/^(.*?) is not defined$/i)
  window[arg] = arg
  doStuff(A)
}
```

But that's redundant and pointless, so now let's take this logic and put it in a function that will automatically define the variable for you in the global scope then call the function again like so:

```
function wrapError(fn){
  try {
    fn()
  }catch(e){
    const [, arg] = e.message.match(/^(.*?) is not defined$/i)
    window[arg] = arg
    wrapError(fn)
  }
}
```

The unfortunate caveat here is that you have to pass a function to `wrapError`, or else `doStuff` will evaluate inline and will throw its error outside the try/catch block.

```
wrapError(()=>doStuff(A, B, C))
```

Finally you end up with the following, which was tested on Chrome on Mac. It's possible that the error message thrown will have a different format or structure and this regex isn't that robust, so keep that in mind.

```js
function doStuff(...args){
  console.log("Args:", ...args)
}

function wrapError(fn){
  try {
    fn()
  }catch(e){
    const [,arg] = e.message.match(/^(.*?) is not defined$/i)
    window[arg] = arg
    wrapError(fn)
  }
}

// With wrapper
wrapError(()=>doStuff(PLZ, DONT, DO, THIS))

// Without wrapper
doStuff(Hello, Error) // ReferenceError
```

Conclusion: Never do this and I hope nobody ever takes this seriously.

Comment: Very well thought out answer, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without a preprocessor, which would clean up the code in advance.

You could take a `const` for `'F'`. But I would not recommend it.

```
const F = 'F';
```

Comment: I'm going to amend my question, I considered that possibility too but it deviates from what I was aiming for of just an automatic conversion into a string.